# How do you get a complete list of A (and AAAA) records for a domain?

Tags: domain-name-system

Let's say I want to know find the A and AAAA records for a domain, for example: `google.com`

I can use `host`:

```
$ host google.com 
google.com has address 172.217.169.46
google.com has IPv6 address 2a00:1450:4009:801::200e
google.com mail is handled by 20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 30 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 40 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 50 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx.l.google.com.
```

But this apparently doesn't list them all, as if I query the name servers directly I get different answers:

```
$  host google.com ns2.google.com
Using domain server:
Name: ns2.google.com
Address: 216.239.34.10#53
Aliases: 

google.com has address 216.58.205.46
google.com has IPv6 address 2a00:1450:4009:808::200e
google.com mail is handled by 30 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 40 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 50 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
```

The results even seems to vary query to query... So I infer there's something going on, with DNS servers not telling the whole picture.

To take another angle, if you go and look on a site like robtex.com, and look up the domain there, there is a long list of IPs which are not being returned by my queries:

https://www.robtex.com/dns-lookup/google.com#records

That currently lists this long collection of IP numbers:

```
 2404:6800:4003:c02::8b
 2404:6800:4004:807::200e
 2404:6800:4006:803::200e
 2607:f8b0:4004:811::200e
 2607:f8b0:4005:802::200e
 2607:f8b0:4005:808::200e
 2607:f8b0:400a:809::200e
 2800:3f0:4001:803::200e
 2a00:1450:400b:805::200e
 74.125.68.100
 74.125.68.101
 74.125.68.102
 74.125.68.113
 74.125.68.138
 74.125.68.139
 172.217.0.46
 172.217.5.110
 172.217.15.110
 172.217.27.78
 172.217.29.14
 172.217.171.14
 216.58.194.174
 216.58.199.46
```

Which if correct, suggests the answers I got from `host` only hint at the true picture.

How can I get a complete and authoritative answer?

Comment: "as if I query the name servers directly I get different answers:" The specific example you took is not a good one: the nameservers give you different IP addresses almost each time you query them. It is the internal rules of the entity you query, and you can obviously not get all possible replies they do. More generally for serious DNS business you should prefer `dig` over `host` or `nslookup`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the client side, you may never get the full picture, as many DNS endpoints are using GeoDNS and other GeoLocation based load balancing.

Assuming, however, that you have access to clients distributed across the globe, you can use GNU dig for this.

You'll first need to find the root name servers to query - to get a list of root name servers simply run `dig`.  Grab one of the output servers (in this example l.root-servers.net) and query it:
`dig @l.root-servers.net -t NS DOMAIN.NEt`
(produces output like this:

```
 ;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
 net.                    172800  IN      NS      a.gtld-servers.net.
 net.                    172800  IN      NS      b.gtld-servers.net.
 net.                    172800  IN      NS      c.gtld-servers.net.
 net.                    172800  IN      NS      d.gtld-servers.net.
 net.                    172800  IN      NS      e.gtld-servers.net.
 net.                    172800  IN      NS      f.gtld-servers.net.
 net.                    172800  IN      NS      g.gtld-servers.net.
 net.                    172800  IN      NS      h.gtld-servers.net.
 net.                    172800  IN      NS      i.gtld-servers.net.
 net.                    172800  IN      NS      j.gtld-servers.net.
 net.                    172800  IN      NS      k.gtld-servers.net.
 net.                    172800  IN      NS      l.gtld-servers.net.
 net.                    172800  IN      NS      m.gtld-servers.net.

 ;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
 a.gtld-servers.net.     172800  IN      A       192.5.6.30
 b.gtld-servers.net.     172800  IN      A       192.33.14.30
 c.gtld-servers.net.     172800  IN      A       192.26.92.30
 d.gtld-servers.net.     172800  IN      A       192.31.80.30
 e.gtld-servers.net.     172800  IN      A       192.12.94.30
 f.gtld-servers.net.     172800  IN      A       192.35.51.30
 g.gtld-servers.net.     172800  IN      A       192.42.93.30
 h.gtld-servers.net.     172800  IN      A       192.54.112.30
 i.gtld-servers.net.     172800  IN      A       192.43.172.30
 j.gtld-servers.net.     172800  IN      A       192.48.79.30
 k.gtld-servers.net.     172800  IN      A       192.52.178.30
 l.gtld-servers.net.     172800  IN      A       192.41.162.30
 m.gtld-servers.net.     172800  IN      A       192.55.83.30
```

That'll give a list of TLD name servers.  Now, if you want a globally complete view, you'll need to perform the remaining queries from clients distributed across the globe (using a CDN or some such).

For a truly complete view, you should iterate through all of these name servers from all of your global client endpoints; but you can likely shortcut that and just query one of them for all the name servers they know of for your target domain:
`dig @a.gtld-servers.net. -t NS DOMAIN.NET`

That'll give you something like this:

```
 ;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
 ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
 ;; QUESTION SECTION:
 ;DOMAIN.NET.                   IN      NS

 ;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
 domain.net.            172800  IN      NS      a.dns.domain.net.
 domain.net.            172800  IN      NS      b.dns.domain.net.
 domain.net.            172800  IN      NS      c.dns.domain.net.

 ;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
 a.dns.domain.net.        172800  IN      A       173.246.98.1
 b.dns.domain.net.        172800  IN      A       213.167.229.1
 c.dns.domain.net.        172800  IN      A       217.70.179.1
```

^^^^ this is your starting list of name servers for domain.net.  Notate them.

Next, iterate through those output name servers and make sure they don't delegate to additional name servers:
`dig @c.dns.domain.net -t NS DOMAIN.NET`

If that produces any name servers you don't have listed from the previous query, add them to your list of DOMAIN.NET name servers to query.

Now, iterate through your list of DOMAIN.NET name servers and query each one like so (where $NAME_SERVER is the name server from your list that you're currently querying):

```
dig -t A @$NAME_SERVER domain.net
dig -t AAAA @$NAME_SERVER domain.net
```

Add the results of both above queries to your list of A and AAAA records for DOMAIN.NET.

Once you've queried all of the authoritative name servers from all of your globally distributed clients, you'll have a fairly complete view.

Comment: Hm, as I feared. Thanks.